# I really need help on how to substitute the string "date" from the test.txt line with the actual date. i tried multiple ways but no luck

Tags: bash, shell, sed

`test.txt` file:

```
today is date
```

Here are scripts I tried so far:

`test.sed` file:

1. `s/date/$(date)/`
2. `s/date/$(date +'%m\ / %d \ / %y')/`

Below is how I run the command line:

1. `sed -r -f test.sed test.txt`
2. `sed -r -E -f test.sed test.txt`

Comment: The `$(....)` syntax is part of the shell grammar. It is not part of the `sed` syntax. If you want to use `-f`, the file must contain a pure _sed_ program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i "s/date/$(date)/g" test.txt
```

This will replace date string with a current date. If you want a more specific format of the date you can add arguments to the date command.

Answer (score 1):

`sed -e "s+date+$(date)+" test.txt`.  We have to use + as the separator because the `date` output includes slashes.

You can't read the commands from a script file, because you need the shell to expand the `$(date)` variable.